# Send email from Tableau: how to split email's body into multiple lines?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Hello Stack Overflow community,
I am trying to send an email from Tableau, but I can't figure it out how to split the body of the email into multiple rows.
I have three fields: ,  and .
The email must be structured in this way:
 with $ in total  revenue in the last 7 days
 with $ in total  revenue in the last 7 days
 with $ in total  revenue in the last 7 days

I've created the following URL action : mailto:XYZ?Business&body=  with total <SUM(Revenue)>  revenue in the last 7 days

When selecting multiple sellers at the same time, I get this:
"Seller A-Seller B-Seller C - with total $15 946-$3 412-$31 505 PD-PD-PA revenue in the last 7 days".

Do you know how (if possible) to split that text in multiple lines?
And if so, how can I send the email automatically, without having to manually click on the seller's name?

Sorry for the silly question, I am relatively new to Tableau.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It used to be possible to [send a formatted email from Tableau](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/format-tableau-subscription-message/). However, I believe this was made not possible as a [security precaution](https://community.tableau.com/s/news/a0A4T000001v3QKUAY/important-adv2020007-html-injection-in-emails) back in 2020.

I haven't tried in later versions of Tableau to know if it's possible again.